# How to get audio using INMP441 with esp32 to Android application for 2 way audio communication?

Tags: android-studio, esp32, audio-streaming, communication, local-network

I want to make a project using the esp32 cam microcontroller and INMP441 sound module to communicate esp32 with an Android application. I want to get audio using the sound module and send it to the Android app, then the mobile app sends audio using its mic to the esp32 speaker. How to do this?

I am still trying to get audio and send it to a mobile app in the local network.